# make nested for loops throw exception

Tags: python

I'm working through Guttag's Python textbook and am stuck on the best way to solve this problem:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter an integer and prints two integers,
>   root and pwr, such that 0 < pwr < 6 and root**pwr is equal to the integer entered by the user.
>   If no such pair of integers exists, it should print a message to that effect.

I came up with one solution on my own that solves the problem for both positive and negative integers, and prints a message when it's not possible: (excuse my debug statements!)

```
x = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
root=abs(x)-1
pwr=0
# first get the non-negative answers
while root**pwr != abs(x):   # 0,6,10
    if root**pwr < abs(x):
        if pwr<6:
            pwr = pwr + 1  # 0,5,10
            # print("st1", root, pwr, root ** pwr) # for debugging
    else:#0
        root = root - 1
        # print("st2",root,pwr,root**pwr) # for debugging
# then make it work for negatives. v messy
if root ** pwr == abs(x):
    if x < 0:
        root = -1 * root
    print(root, "to the", pwr, "power is", x)
else:
    print("no such values")
```

But on StackOverflow, I found this much more elegant solution. The problem is, I can't figure out how to add a "no such values" statement:

```
integer = int(input("integer input:"))
for root in range(0,integer): # this works because it automagically does negatives for negative numbers.
    for pwr in range(1,6):
        if root ** pwr == integer:
            print(root, pwr)
```

I tried adding an `else: print()` to the end of that last if statement but it printed `no such vals` for every pair of root,pwr that didn't work, rather than only if it couldn't find one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "this works because it automagically does negatives for negative numbers" - no it doesn't.

Comment: oh wow, I missed that! so I would probably need to do a similar kind of `abs()`-wrangling to get that shorter version to work, regardless. (also, thank you!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OLD Answer**
To answer your question on how to make the program print out only when it couldn't find one is to use `else` on the outer `for` loop:

```
integer = int(input("integer input:"))
for root in range(0,integer): # this works because it automatically does negatives for negative numbers.
    for pwr in range(1,6):
        if root ** pwr == integer:
            print(root, pwr)
else:
    print('no such vals')
```

**Edited:**
I guess the easiest way is to use flag:

```
found = False
integer = int(input("integer input:"))
for root in range(0,integer): # this works because it automatically does negatives for negative numbers.
    for pwr in range(1,6):
        if root ** pwr == integer:
            print(root, pwr)
            found = True
if not found:
    print('no such vals')
```

Comment: This will print `"no such vals"` even if the value exists. because there is no break statement in this loop.

Comment: yes, this is the probelm - I can get it to print "no such vals" for every invalid pair it tries, but not for just when it can't find anything.

Comment: @oldwooki A `try` statement’s `else` clause runs when no `exception` occurs, and a loop’s `else` clause runs when no `break` occurs. For more details  please have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

```
integer = int(input("integer input:"))
Found = False
for root in range(0,integer):
    for pwr in range(1,6):
        if root ** pwr == integer:
            print(root, pwr)
            Found = True
            break
    if Found:
        break
else:
    print('no such vals')
```

Loop breaks when it finds the first matching pair. If the loop didn't find a matching pair then will run the else statement.

Comment: @trish_s what about now? This will print "no such values" only if it didn't find a matching pair. And also breaks the loop immediately if it finds a matching pair.

Answer (score 0):

```py
integer = int(input("integer input:"))
true = 0
for root in range(0,integer): # this works because it automagically does negatives for negative numbers.
    for pwr in range(1,6):
        if root ** pwr == integer:
            print(root, pwr)
            true = 1
else:
    if(true == 0):
        print("no such")
```

Use the flags instead in that case the code will print only 1 time if there are no values
Also don't forget it does not handle negatives.